# Already a Virtual device is online in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am using the old SDK which is copied at reinstallation time of windows. I linked my new android studio with the SDK. When I try to run the app in virtual device it shows already a virtual device is online. How can I clear that?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: DId you restart Android Studio? Did you clean your peoject before running it? Do you see the virtual device which is online in `Select Deployment Target`? How many other devices do you see there if yes? Can you run your app on a real device?

Comment: DId you restart Android Studio? YES

Did you clean your peoject before running it? YES

Do you see the virtual device which is online in Select Deployment Target? No

How many other devices do you see there if yes?

 Can you run your app on a real device? yes

Comment: Why don't you create a new emulator?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 2.1.2 you can solve your problem by creating a new emulator.

1. Press: `Run`

[image]

2. Create a New Emulator using the Virtual Device Configuration

[image]

Comment: I tried creating new emulator but it shows a blank black screen now i again created one and log is as follows

Comment: emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateCheck: current version '24.4.1', last version '24.4.1'

Comment: Can you choose your new emulator when running your app? Does the black screen come after running the app on the new emulator?

Comment: Can you edit the original thread above and post your `build.gradle` file? the one in src.